# What is the fastest way to load an svg in Xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin.forms, skiasharp

I would like to use svgs in my xamarin forms

1. It would eliminate 99% of pngs
2. Images resolution is much better.

However I have noticed that when loading the svgs (FFImageLoading nuget) I get a lag of a second , something noticible when loading an svg.

Is svg not appropriate for xamarin forms apps?

Suggestions on how to load the svg without lag?

Comment: Do you use SkiaSharp.Svg to load svg file? Can you show simple demo that can reproduce your issue here?

Comment: @CherryBu hi thanks for your reply. I am using FFImageLoading  and their svgImagecache which internally uses skiasharp  link https://github.com/luberda-molinet/FFImageLoading/blob/master/samples/ImageLoading.Forms.Sample/Shared/Pages/SvgSamplePage.xaml .